# Drag and drop a pawn

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, bind

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Label, NSEW

class CanvasChecker(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, parent, n_pixels_per_case=60):

        self.checker = {(7, 0): 'o', (7, 2): 'o', (7, 4): 'o', (7, 6): 'o', (6, 1): 'o', 
                (6, 3): 'o', (6, 5): 'o', (6, 7): 'o', (5, 0): 'o', (5, 2): 'o', (5, 4): 'o',
                (5, 6): 'o', (2, 1): 'x', (2, 3): 'x', (2, 5): 'x', (2, 7): 'x', (1, 0): 'x',
                (1, 2): 'x', (1, 4): 'x', (1, 6): 'x', (0, 1): 'x', (0, 3): 'x', (0, 5): 'x',
                (0, 7): 'x'}

        self.n_pixels_per_case = n_pixels_per_case

        width = 8 * n_pixels_per_case
        height = 8 * n_pixels_per_case

        super().__init__(parent, width=width, height=height)

        self.bind('<Configure>', self.redimension)

    def draw_cases(self):
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                beg_line = i * self.n_pixels_per_case
                end_line = beg_line + self.n_pixels_per_case
                beg_column = j * self.n_pixels_per_case
                end_column = beg_column + self.n_pixels_per_case

                if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                    color = '#E88515'
                color = '#DDDDFF'

                self.create_rectangle(beg_column, beg_line, end_column, end_line, fill=color, tags='case')

    def draw_pieces(self):
        for position in self.checker:
            coordinate_y = position[0] * self.n_pixels_per_case + self.n_pixels_per_case // 2
            coordinate_x = position[1] * self.n_pixels_per_case + self.n_pixels_per_case // 2

            piece = self.checker[position]

            if piece == 'o':
                icon = "\u26C0"
            elif piece == 'O':
                icon = "\u26C1"
            elif piece == 'x':
                icon = "\u26C2"
            else:
                icon = "\u26C3"

            character_police = ('Already Seen', self.n_pixels_per_case//2)
            self.create_text(coordinate_x, coordinate_y, text=icon, font=character_police, tags='piece')

    def redimension(self, event):

        new_size = min(event.width, event.height)
        self.n_pixels_per_case = new_size // 8
        self.actualise()

    def actualise(self):
        self.delete('case')
        self.draw_cases()
        self.delete('piece')
        self.draw_pieces()


class Game(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas_checker = CanvasChecker(self, 60)
        self.canvas_checker.grid(sticky=NSEW)

        self.messages = Label(self)
        self.messages.grid()

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Game()
    window.mainloop()
```

I have a checker-board. I would be interested in dragging and dropping each pawn in the different cases, but I am confused how I can do it. I have thought using `my_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", move)`, but I am not really sure how to play with that in the above code. Right now, I can only see the different white and black piece without being able to move them.

How can I drag and drop pawn on the checker-board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is copy some code from the highest-voted answer in the question that you linked to (in an earlier version of your question), and then adjust the bindings to work on the tag "piece" rather than "token".

First, copy the functions `drag_start`, `drag_stop`, and `drag` from that code into your `CanvasChecker` class. Change `self.canvas` to `self` in that copied code.

Next, add this line somewhere in the `__init__` function:

```
self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
```

Finally, add the following bindings, also in the `__init__`:

```
self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_start)
self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drag_stop)
self.tag_bind("piece", "<B1-Motion>", self.drag)
```

You'll need to add logic for determining whether the move is legal or not, but this answers the question about how to move the piece with the mouse.

---

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Label, NSEW

class CanvasChecker(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, parent, n_pixels_per_case=60):

        self.checker = {(7, 0): 'o', (7, 2): 'o', (7, 4): 'o', (7, 6): 'o', (6, 1): 'o',
                (6, 3): 'o', (6, 5): 'o', (6, 7): 'o', (5, 0): 'o', (5, 2): 'o', (5, 4): 'o',
                (5, 6): 'o', (2, 1): 'x', (2, 3): 'x', (2, 5): 'x', (2, 7): 'x', (1, 0): 'x',
                (1, 2): 'x', (1, 4): 'x', (1, 6): 'x', (0, 1): 'x', (0, 3): 'x', (0, 5): 'x',
                (0, 7): 'x'}

        self.n_pixels_per_case = n_pixels_per_case

        width = 8 * n_pixels_per_case
        height = 8 * n_pixels_per_case

        super().__init__(parent, width=width, height=height)

        self.bind('<Configure>', self.redimension)

        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
        self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_start)
        self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drag_stop)
        self.tag_bind("piece", "<B1-Motion>", self.drag)


    def draw_cases(self):
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                beg_line = i * self.n_pixels_per_case
                end_line = beg_line + self.n_pixels_per_case
                beg_column = j * self.n_pixels_per_case
                end_column = beg_column + self.n_pixels_per_case

                if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                    color = '#E88515'
                color = '#DDDDFF'

                self.create_rectangle(beg_column, beg_line, end_column, end_line, fill=color, tags='case')

    def draw_pieces(self):
        for position in self.checker:
            coordinate_y = position[0] * self.n_pixels_per_case + self.n_pixels_per_case // 2
            coordinate_x = position[1] * self.n_pixels_per_case + self.n_pixels_per_case // 2

            piece = self.checker[position]

            if piece == 'o':
                icon = "\u26C0"
            elif piece == 'O':
                icon = "\u26C1"
            elif piece == 'x':
                icon = "\u26C2"
            else:
                icon = "\u26C3"

            character_police = ('Already Seen', self.n_pixels_per_case//2)
            self.create_text(coordinate_x, coordinate_y, text=icon, font=character_police, tags='piece')

    def redimension(self, event):

        new_size = min(event.width, event.height)
        self.n_pixels_per_case = new_size // 8
        self.actualise()

    def actualise(self):
        self.delete('case')
        self.draw_cases()
        self.delete('piece')
        self.draw_pieces()

    def drag_start(self, event):
        """Begining drag of an object"""
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def drag_stop(self, event):
        """End drag of an object"""
        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["item"] = None
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0

    def drag(self, event):
        """Handle dragging of an object"""
        # compute how much the mouse has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
        delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

class Game(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas_checker = CanvasChecker(self, 60)
        self.canvas_checker.grid(sticky=NSEW)

        self.messages = Label(self)
        self.messages.grid()

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Game()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Bryan-Oakley This makes a bad answer, since you're merely instructing the OP on what to do without elaborating.

Comment: @Space: why? If you let me know, perhaps I can make the answer better.

Comment: @Space: the elaboration is in the inline comments of the copied code. The OP knows of the existence of a better answer but had some sort of mental block for applying that code to their code. It seemed pretty clear from their answers to comments that they were never going to figure it out.

Comment: I understand that OP has linked to answer (that they removed), you don't have to explain the mechanics of the game, but rather why and where their code was failing.

Comment: @Space: nothing in their code was failing. They refused to show code that attempted to move the object even after I asked.